# How can I scrape the Ph elements of this list page?

Tags: web-scraping

[elements required](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JcEmJ.jpg)Hello I would like to scrap the Ph values of this page and on the website. I tried yet many things but nothing with a really usefulness. I get the list but not the element. I tried a dataframe too but colaboratory ask me for dtype and I don't where I have to introduce it.

Please could you help me please? I'm starting with scraping

[ph éléments on Farmi page](https://www.farmi.com/Soufflet-FR/fr_FR/EUR/Sant%C3%A9-du-v%C3%A9g%C3%A9tal-/Herbicides/Roundup-Flash-Plus/p/19795520)

Comment: _I tried yet many things_, please explain what you tried ?

Comment: Please read [ask] and show us your [mre].

Comment: I tried to exclude "li" and "dl" too. I succeeded in printing the data but all in 1 column. So I wanted to separate it in 2 columns as key; value but what I tried didn't success and above all I basically I didn't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re
res=requests.get("https://www.farmi.com/Soufflet-FR/fr_FR/EUR/Sant%C3%A9-du-v%C3%A9g%C3%A9tal-/Herbicides/Roundup-Flash-Plus/p/19795520")
soup=BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
```

First find data which is required and filter it using `find_all` method and iterate over to get only specific data using `re` module to find matching string data

```
all_data=soup.find_all("dl")
tags=[]
for d in  all_data:
    main_data=d.find("li",text=re.compile("Ph "))
    if main_data is not None:
        tags.append(d)
```

Now iterate over  `tags` to get data in form of key-value pair

```
final_dict={}
for t in tags:
    name=t.find("li").get_text(strip=True).replace("&nbsp","")
    print(name)
    final_dict[name]=t.find("p").get_text(strip=True).replace("&nbsp","")
```

Output:

```
{'Ph :': '4.5-5.5 (10 g/l à 23°C) ', 'Ph max :': '5.5 ', 'Ph min :': '4.5 '}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! Ihave a question : What did you use "lxml"? Y don't know it

Comment: `lxml` is parser you can refer documentation for more parser avail in `bs4` if you find answer useful you an upvote or marked as answer

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add the name of the product and the amm with the "ph" data. I get it so i try to go to a dataframe that would easier to manipulate but I failed. I don't how could i do it. Any help please, i would`enter code here` be so grateful

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

import requests
import csv

import re
res=requests.get("https://www.farmi.com/Soufflet-FR/fr_FR/EUR/Sant%C3%A9- 
du-v%C3%A9g%C3%A9tal-/Herbicides/Roundup-Flash-Plus/p/19795520")
soup=BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")

all_data=soup.find("ph")
title=soup.find('title')
amm=soup.select('body > main > div.lg\:flex-grow > div.main__inner-wrapper 
> div.main-container > div > div.lg\:flex-grow.lg\:w-8\/12 > div > div > 
div.lg\:flex-grow.lg\:w-5\/12.lg\:pl-20.lg\:pr-40 > div.name > p')
tags=[]
print(title,amm,all_data)

for d in  all_data:
    main_data=d.find("li",text=re.compile("Ph "))
    if main_data is not None:
        tags.append(d)

final_dict={}
for t in tags:
    name=t.find("li").get_text(strip=True).replace("&nbsp","")
    print(name)
    final_dict[name]=t.find("p").get_text(strip=True).replace("&nbsp","")

print(title,amm,final_dict)

complete_data = title,amm,final_dict

print(complete_data)

data_table=pd.DataFrame(complete_data) here It fails
```

Comment: Could you help me please? Many thanks!